# Does the Maya FBX 2013.3 exporter write tangent and binormal data?

Tags: maya, fbx

I'm making an XNA game at the moment and I'm trying to knock out my bump map shader right now. However when I compile the game crashes at the mesh.Draw() line and tells me TANGENT0 is missing. Apparently the FBX 2012 exporter didn't export tangent and binormal data properly, and I'm still having this problem despite installing the most recent exporter for Maya 2012.

For the record the plug-in readme tells me that bug is fixed and I am checking 'Tangents and Binormals' when I export.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes it does. When adding your FBX models to your game content, right click the file, go to properties and set the 'Generate Tangent Frames' to true.

Comment: Mind elaborating on what properties did you change? Others might benefit.